# Binance API R GET Request

Tags: r, binance

I am trying to perform a simple GET request on the Binance API with the httr package. According to the API docs (https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) the below R code should return results similar to what is in the brackets.

```
{
  "symbol": "LTCBTC",
  "price": "4.00000200"
}
```

```
library(httr)

query_params <- list(symbol = 'LTCBTC')  
get_result <- GET("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price", query = query_params)
```

Everything looks correct in my results with a status code of 200 but the data I actually requested is nowhere in the listed items. When I look in  `get_result[["request"]][["output"]]` there is nothing. I have tried similar GET requests for almost every public API endpoint but cannot get anything to actually return. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(httr)

GET(
  url = "https://api.binance.com",
  path = "api/v3/ticker/price",
  query = list (
    symbol = "LTCBTC"
  )
) -> res

content(res, as="parsed")
## $symbol
## [1] "LTCBTC"
## 
## $price
## [1] "0.02311900"
```

seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide an answer, using existing `R` packages that are available, for future visitors.

One of such is the `cryptoQuotes`-package, which extracts `OHLC` data from Binance using high level functions.

```r
## 1) get BTCUSDT pair 
## from Binance spot market
## for 15m intervals
btc <- cryptoQuotes::getQuote(
  ticker   = 'BTCUSDT',
  interval = '15m',
  source   = 'binance',
  futures  = FALSE
)
```

The `btc` can passed into all the relevant functions in `quantmod` and `TTR`. Below is an example with a candlestick chart with MACD and Bollinger Bands.

```r
## 1) chart using
## quantmod
quantmod::chartSeries(
  x =    tail(btc, 100),
  name = 'BTCUSDT',
  theme = quantmod::chartTheme('white')
)

## 2) add MACD
## and Bollinger BAnds
quantmod::addMACD()
quantmod::addBBands()
```

[image: A candlestick chart with MACD and Bollinger Bands using Quantmod and TTR.]

The package can be installed via `CRAN` as follows,

```r
## install package
install.packages('cryptoQuotes')
```